# Problems with mysql in debian 7

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

Hi friends good morning!, I find a big problem to start, stop and restart service mysql in debian 7.
Shows me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server localhost failed
Error Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'
```

1 Get the file / etc / mysql / debian.cnf the old password that had the "debian-sys-maint" user with a simple "cat" can be seen:

```
server:/# cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = DEBUSERPASSWORD
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = DEBUSERPASSWORD
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

As seen there, "DEBUSERPASSWORD" is the password ...

February. Again We add to our existing user database ...

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'DEBUSERPASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: it says that user 'debian-sys-maint' does not have permission, just grant him the proper privileges!

Comment: You try but it shows me this other error:
ERROR 1045 (28000) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: that's odd, can you show what have you tried exactly

Comment: I've added to the description @mamdouhalramadan